# Dictionary of Words: need to scan each element for word length and make searchable

Tags: java

I have converted a file of words into a String array. I need to somehow convert the Array into a list of word lengths and make it searchable. In other words, I need to be able to enter a word length (say, 5) and be presented with only the words that have a word length of five. Help?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {    
  String token1 = ""; 
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("No.txt"));
  List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scan.hasNext()){ 
           token1 = scan.next(); 
           temps.add(token1);
     }
  scan.close();
  String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);
  for (String s : tempsArray) {
```

Comment: Loop through the array, compare the length?

Comment: Have a look at [Google Guava's `Multimap`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap), e.g. you could use a `Multimap<Integer, String>` to collect the words by length.

Comment: Any comments/feedback on my answer? Does it help; could I add something in order to make it acceptable for you?

Answer (score 4):

You don't use an array for that. The things you need are collections, more precisely: [Maps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and [Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html); as you want to use a `Map<Integer, List<String>>`.

Meaning: a map that uses "word length" as key; and the mapped entry is a list containing all those words with that length. Here is a bit of code to get you started:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> wordsByLength = new HashMap<>();
// now you have to fill that map; lets assume tempsArray contains all your words
for (String s : tempsArray) {
  List<String> listForCurrentLength = wordsByLength.get(s.length());
  if (listForCurrentLength == null) {
    listForCurrentLength = new ArrayList<>();
  }
  listForCurrentLength.add(s);
  wordsByLength.put(s.length(), listForCurrentLength);
```

The idea is basically to iterate that array you already got; and for each string in there ... put it into that map; depending on its length.

( the above was just written down; neither compiled nor tested; as said it is meant as "pseudo code" to get you going )